# How to add the sender of a command's name into a list in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create my own Discord bot using Discord.py, and to keep track of individual player's points, i used a list, one with the players name, and another with the player's points, and both were the same number on that list. What I am trying to do is add the name of the person who sent the command to the list of players.
**Code:**

```
    @bot.command()
    async def pointadd(ctx, amount, points=points, players=players):
        yes = 1
        for x in players:
            if players[x] == {ctx.message.author}:
                yes = ('Yes')
                level = x
        if yes == ('Yes'):
            points[level] = (points[level] + amount)
            await ctx.send(points[level])
        else:
            players.append(ctx.message.author)
            points.append('0')
```

**The error:**

```
Ignoring exception in command pointadd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/pipy_bot/bot.py", line 58, in pointadd
    if players[x] == {ctx.message.author}:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Also i could use some help making this neater.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a `players` list element, which, I gess, is a `discord.Member` object. List indices must be integers and nothing else so you have this error. You'd have to write:

```py
@bot.command()
async def pointadd(ctx, amount, points=points, players=players):
    found = False
    for x in players:
    if x == ctx.message.author:
        found = True
        level = players.index(x)
    if found:
        points[level] = (int(points[level]) + amount)
        await ctx.send(points[level])
    else:
        players.append(ctx.message.author)
        points.append('0')
```

(`points[level]` must be an integer in order to make calculations so I wrote `int(points[level])`)

Instead of using lists, you could use dictionnaries:

```py
#Your points definition
points = {}
```

```py
#Your pointadd command
@bot.command()
async def pointadd(ctx, amount: int, points=points):
    try:
        points[ctx.author.id] += amount
    except:
        points[ctx.author.id] = 0
    await ctx.send(points[ctx.author.id])
```

In the end, your `points` dictionnary would look like this:

```py
{
    'user_id_1': xp_amount_1
    'user_id_2': xp_amount_2
    ...
}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/pipy_bot/bot.py", line 59, in pointadd
    points[ctx.author.id] = 0
IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Thats the error that occured when using the dictionary version.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/657259687351418880/761285425851007006/unknown.png is the error with the other one you put.

Comment: What's the type of `players` in your code?  Also, I fixed the dictionnary part

Comment: and the dictionary still isnt working.     points[ctx.author.id] = 0
IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Comment: I don't have any errors using dictionnaries, are you sure you set `points` as a dict ? Also, are you sure that `points` is a list (for the first code I gave)

Comment: i fixed it. i made a new python file and imported it into the command, and inside the file was where the dictionare was defined. it works now. thank you for your help